# How to upload file PDF with laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, pdf

How to upload file pdf in web and the file name can to be a link to view the file in web. I use laravel framework with Mysql

Comment: Laravel has excellent documentation. Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload any file to your storage in laravel you should use:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('filename.pdf', File::get($request['file']))
```

According to link of the file you should get path of your file and then display it in  tag.

Getting file path:

```
storage_path('app\public\file.pdf');
```

Of course you should use that in your view in double braces {{ }}